# What are the standard parallelism terms for CUDA concepts?

Tags: cuda, terminology

*Note: Sorry this is not exactly a programming question; please migrate it if there is a more appropriate stackexchange site (I didn't see any; it's not theoretical CS).*

I'm looking for less CUDA-specific terms for certain GPU-programming related concepts. OpenCL is somewhat helpful. I'm looking for "parallelism-theory" / research paper words more than practical keywords for a new programming language. Please feel free to post additions and corrections.

#### "warp"

I usually equate this to SIMD-width.

#### "block"

*alternatives*

- "group" (OpenCL).
- "thread-block" -- want something shorter
- "tile"

#### "syncthreads"

It seems "barrier" is the more general word, used in multicore CPU programming I think, and OpenCL. Is there anything else?

#### "shared memory"

*alternatives*

- "local memory" (OpenCL).
- "tile/block cache"?

#### "kernel"

*alternatives*

- "CTA / Cooperative Thread Array" (OpenCL). way too much of a mouthful, dunno what it means.
- "GPU program" -- would be difficult to distinguish between kernel invocations.
- "device computation"?

Comment: You should really stick to standard terminology, especially in academic writing. If you want to use terms that make clear the properties of these things, then it's better to write it out, not invent new terms. There's nothing wrong with giving standard terminology and then providing one or two sentences to define it. Also, not only is this not the stackexchange for this question, but this is not a question that is well-suited to any Q&A site; this is begging for argument, discussion, opinion, and the like.

Comment: @Patrick87, You have a good point to stick with standard terminology. I've revised the question to read "what is the standard terminology". It seems some papers borrow a few CUDA words and a few more general words. Please remove your downvote if the edits are sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't really exact enough technology neutral terms for detailed specifics of CUDA and openCL and if you used more generic terms such as "shared memory" or "cache" you wouldn't be making clear precisely what you meant

I think you might have to stick to the terms from one technology (perhaps putting the other in brackets) or use "his/her" type language and add extra explanation if a term doens't have a corresponding use in the other